# Disadvantage of multiple tomcat instance in single server

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-14.04

We are Having One single Ubuntu server in cloud and we had planned to deploy Two Tomcat instance in single server.
It is advisable to deploy two tomcat Instance in a single server
Please tell what are the disadvantages Using two tomcat in single server

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Its truly adviseable, because there is only one tomcat which is consuming resources for its system operations.

The disadvantages are following:

- Systemchanges on Tomcat system level require both application to stop
- port or network settings have to differ, both applications cannot use same ports
- high resource consumption of one application can slow down the other application, as there is only one ressource pool to use

But Tomcat is designed to handle more applications than one. Ressource consumption is in a cloud environment truly no problem and reducing the memory stamp for the tomcat itself is a good thing.